# Get Average Increase Over Time

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am using increase on a counter metric to get the increase in HTTP connections for the last 10 minutes:

```
increase(http_connections{kind="test"}[10m])
```

This expression returns two distinct values within my test environment:

```
15.789
12.631
```

How can I get the average of the above values?

[image]

Comment: Can we have more info about why you're getting two values ? I guess it's because you different values on one label

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA The HTTP requests are being received as test data from a single source. Honestly, I'm not entirely sure (new to Prometheus) why I'm getting two values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To flatten that out, you can either increase the interval, simply query for the increase of the last 20min and then divide that by two:

```
increase(http_connections{kind="test"}[20m]) / 2
```

(or query the last 30 min and divide by 3)...

Alternatively you can also use the `avg_over_time()` function with subquery:

```
avg_over_time(increase(http_connections{kind="test"}[10m])[10m:1m])
```

this will take one value per minute over the last 10 minutes and use the average of these 10 values as the current value

Comment: The second example (avg_over_time) was exactly what I was looking for. This is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The prometheus documentation is not clear about the meaning of `[10m:1m] `. Is anybody having an explanation, especially to what 1m is referring ?

Comment: The meaning is take da datapoint for every minute (the second value) and then calculate (in that case) the average over 10 minutes. With the second value you can configure the precission and the procession time.